# Convert a list of vector to a vector with R

Tags: r

I try to tokenize a vector of sentence like this :

```
tok <- tokenize_sentences(tolower(SnowballC::wordStem(IRC, language = 'fr')))
```

I get this sample of result :

```
....
[[995]]
[1] "aucun dialogue j'envoie des fax ...."

[[996]]
[1] "je trouve ...pour 1 jour..."

[[997]]
[1] "satisf"

[[998]]
[1] "bon contact ..."
...
```

Iwould like to know if is there any way to convert it into this :

```
....
[995]
"aucun dialogue j'envoie des fax ...."

[996]
 "je trouve ...pour 1 jour..."

[997]
 "satisf"

[998]
"bon contact ..."
...
```

Thank you

Comment: `unlist`. `purrr::flatten_chr`

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: In this case I should delete my question?